# How to show Highstock tooltip to nearest point in 2-D distance?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When plotting many series on the same graph, is it possible for the tooltip to snap to the closest point in 2-d distance as opposed to the closest in x-axis value only. In this situation, it's impossible to tell which series is which from the color alone and snapping to the closest x-axis value is pretty useless as it basically hops randomly among the many series all having a data point around the same x-value.

I didn't find a way to set up the tooltip this way, but algorithmically it's really not that expensive as one can simply pick out for each series the closest x-value data point and then pick among these the point with the shortest 2-d distance (or even just the closest y-value point as usually x-values are much more densely packed than y-values).

**Update** I played with the `findNearestPointBy` suggested below, which should do what I want except I'm actually using a `stockChart`. It appears that `stockChart` behaves differently from a `chart` - see [stockChart](http://jsfiddle.net/3d7hqa8d/8/) vs. [chart](http://jsfiddle.net/3d7hqa8d/9/)

1. `findNearestPointBy` does not seem to make a difference. If you place mouse directly above either of the two points next to the "bump" but at the height of the bump, the tooltip snaps to the bump on `chart` but to the lower points on `stockChart`.
2. when hovering near the points from both series at the same x-value, `stochChart` tooltip shows both series whereas `chart` tooltip only shows the series whose nearest point is closer - I much prefer the latter as I want the tooltip to tell me which series the nearest point belongs to.

**Update 2** I asked the same question at Highcharts support page, and was pointed to the solution. Adding `tooltip: {shared: false}` solves both of my issues [stockChart v2](http://jsfiddle.net/3d7hqa8d/10/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [Series.findNearestPointBy](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.findNearestPointBy) option to `'xy'`.

From API:

> **findNearestPointBy: String**
>
> Determines whether the series should look for the nearest point in
>   both dimensions or just the x-dimension when hovering the series.
>   Defaults to 'xy' for scatter series and 'x' for most other series. If
>   the data has duplicate x-values, it is recommended to set this to 'xy'
>   to allow hovering over all points.
>
> Applies only to series types using nearest neighbor search (not direct hover) for tooltip.
>
> *src: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.findNearestPointBy*

example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/findnearestpointby/

Comment: very promising option introduced since 5.0.10, but it seems that "Applied only to series types..." made it not work for my case - I'll update my question with details.

Comment: Found the additional option needed for stockChart, so I'll accept this answer.